# Function to find() in all instances

Tags: python

Can you please fix this code. I'm trying to use string.find() to find all cases in the given range (i to j)

```
def multi_find(seq, subseq, i, j):
list = []
while i != -1 and i < j:
    list.append(seq.find(subseq,i,j))
    i = seq.find(subseq,i,j) + 1
return list


print multi_find(seq, subseq, i, j)
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code?

Comment: It doesn't work. error in the function

Comment: And what is the error message? It would be easier for everyone if you would post it with your question (and the full traceback, too).

Comment: It doesn't show anything. completely blank. Also breaks my computer every time I run it.

Comment: This code can't break your computer. Can you post more context?

Comment: Run the code, it doesn't show anything and I have to quit out of terminal.

Comment: seq.find will return -1 when there is no match, so i = seq.find() + 1 will make i == 0, causeing infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def multi_find(seq, subseq, i, j):
    lst = []
    loc = seq.find(subseq, i, j) # location of subseq

    while loc != -1:
        lst.append(loc)
        i = loc + 1
        loc = seq.find(subseq, i, j)
    return lst
```

I think it's clearer to use `i`, `j` as the range where to search in `seq` and use another variable `loc` to keep the result of the search.

Comment: I think you don't worry about i < j,  i >= j will cause swq.find to return -1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be closer to what you are trying to do.

```
import sys

def multi_find(seq, subseq, i, j):
    list = []
    for x in xrange(j - i):
        temp = seq.find(subseq, x + i, j)
        if(temp != -1):
            list.append(temp)
            x += sys.getsizeof(subseq)
        else:
            x += 1
    return list
```

It runs ad returns the number of token that is the sub string but I'm not quite sure how you want to increment your i.